# How to update field when user has logged in?

Tags: apex, batch

I have a requirement where I need to send a reminder to the user who has not logged in past xx days eg(1) and after sending this reminder he will have 2 days to log in to avoid being disabled.

I wrote a batch but I don't know how may I implement a solution that he will be deactivated after these 3 days counting based on last received reminder.

So for example - User logged in yesterday eg(22 Sep) so today (23 Sep) should receive a reminder that after 2 days his account will be deactivated (25 Sep). But when he log in 24 Sep he should receive a notification on 25 Sep that he has again 2 days to log in.

This is my code - could someone help me out with how to implement it ?

```
global class UserLoginReminderBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    Date todayDate = System.today();
    Integer getDay = todayDate.Day() + 2;
    Date deactivateDate = todayDate.addDays(1);
    Integer currentMonth = todayDate.month();
    Map<Integer,String> monthNames = new Map<Integer,String>{
        1 => 'January',
        2 => 'February',
        3 => 'March',
        4 => 'April',
        5 => 'May',
        6 => 'June',
        7 => 'July',
        8 => 'August',
        9 => 'September',
        10 => 'October',
        11 => 'November',
        12 => 'December'
    };

Set<String> profileNames = new Set<String>{
'System Administrator',
'Chatter Free User'};


String query = 'SELECT Id, Email, LastLoginDate, Profile.Name ' + 
'FROM User ' +
'WHERE IsActive = TRUE AND LastLoginDate < NEXT_N_DAYS:1 AND Profile.Name NOT IN :profileNames';

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<User> scope){
        User user = scope[0];
        List<User> usersListToDeactivate = new List<User>();

        for(User userRecord : scope){
            User usr = (user)userRecord;
            user.Ready_For_Deactivate__c = TRUE;
            usersListToDeactivate.add(user);
        }

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        email.setToAddresses(new String[] {user.Email});
        email.setSubject('SFDC Reminder');
        email.setTargetObjectId(user.Id);
        email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        String emailBody = '<b> Hi, </b> <br>' + 
        'This is reminder because <b>you have not logged in for more than 1 day.</b>' +;
        email.setHtmlBody(emailBody);
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});

        if(todayDate == deactivateDate AND user.Ready_For_Deactivate__c == TRUE){
            for(User us : usersListToDeactivate){
                us.IsActive = FALSE;
                us.Ready_For_Deactivate__c = FALSE;
            }
        }
        update usersListToDeactivate;

}
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can divide current solution to 2 batches - first for email reminder, second to deactivate users

Batch1 code

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Email, Ready_For_Deactivate__c FROM User WHERE IsActive = TRUE AND LastLoginDate = YESTERDAY]);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<User> scope) {
    for (User u : scope) {
        u.Ready_For_Deactivate__c = true;

        // build mail message and add to list
    }
    update scope;
    //send mail
}
```

Batch2 code

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT IsActive FROM User WHERE IsActive = TRUE AND LastLoginDate < LAST_N_DAYS:3]);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<User> scope) {
    for (User u : scope) {
        u.IsActive = false;
    }
    update scope;
}
```

Idea is to select data that needs to be processed

Date Formats and Date Literals in WHERE Clauses documentation (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)

Thanks